# SAS HBA card or integrated with MB?

Tags: sas

I need an entry level virtualization server for a few people and I like the Fujitsu line of this kind, but they all seem to have built-in SATA disk interfaces.. I'd like to use SAS disk and apparently there are some SAS interface cards I could use but I have never used such cards and wonder if it is a good idea (re reliability and performance) or should I go with integrated SAS controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PCIe SAS HBAs is quite a common solution and nothing to worry about. There is no difference regarding performance or reliability I am aware of.

Comment: Sure there is nothing wrong with PCI SAS controllers. The good ones are even better than some integrated. Just go with the big players (LSI, Adaptec, Intel) and you shall be fine.